# Need help verifying my program using statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, gambling

I'm writing a video poker simulator and I am trying to verify it is working correctly by looking at the results.  To understand the operation, it works as follows:

- Generate a random hand
- Apply a strategy to the hand to determine the cards to discard
- Discard those cards and get new random cards from the remaining deck
- Determine if the resulting hand gets any payout and, if so, add it to the results

Long story short, when I'm doing this I find that even when I do a large number of trials (400m) my payout percentage is about 0.1% lower than it should be.  I should be getting around 99.54% but I'm actually getting around 99.44%.

What I'd like to know is, given N hands, how can I determine the likelihood of being off X% if I know the expected variance of the game?  [Here are relevant statistics on the game.](https://wizardofodds.com/games/video-poker/strategy/a-1-b-74-c-1-d-0-d-1-d-2-d-3-d-4-d-6-d-9-d-25-d-50-d-800/)

As you can see, that page shows the probability of each hand occurring when using proper strategy, how many hands (on average) it will take for the hand to occur, as well as the variance.  It also sums up everything so there's an overall variance for the game.  What/how can I use this in conjunction with my program results to help verify correctness?  If necessary my program can also produce statistics about how often those hands were hit in the simulation to match up with the probability column.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really possible to find your error without seeing the commented simulation program. But, having tried similar simulations, let me venture a guess. The definitions of the various 'kinds' of hands are very tricky, and it is easy to make a 'small' mistake in logic. (For example: 'Four of a kind', 'Three of a kind', and 'Two pair' can't overlap.)

Comment: I'll be looking to correct an error, but more than that I want to know about the statistics side of things.  Even once I do find some logic error I still want to be able to say "OK my program returns some amount over this many trials and thus I can say with some amount of confidence that the operation is correct because statistically the results make sense"

Comment: If you do many iterations $m$ in a simulation, the average of the payouts ought to be close to normal. So also find the SD of the payouts. Then roughly speaking your 95% margin of simulation error for the avg is $\pm 2 SD/\sqrt{m}.$ Want to see a simpler simulation as an example?

Comment: No, I think this will suffice.  Thanks!  I do have one other semi-related question though.  What would this sort of simulation formally be called?  Monte Carlo simulation?  Stochastic simulation?  I'm not 100% sure of the correct jargon here.

Comment: 'Monte Carlo' is probably the best key word for a search.